# Does the Twitter app for iPhone consumes from the Twitter API?

Tags: twitter

I was wondering if the Twitter app for iPhone developed by Twitter consumes from the Twitter API, or just hits the Twitter´s database directly to retrive any type of information. I'm researching about this, and it seems there's no information about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does use the API, according to the [Twitter Engineering Blog](http://engineering.twitter.com/2010/09/tech-behind-new-twittercom.html)

> One of the most important architectural changes is that Twitter.com is now a client of our own API. It fetches data from the same endpoints that the mobile site, our apps for iPhone, iPad, Android, and every third-party application use.